# T-SQL for finding Redundant Indexes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

Is anyone aware of a T-SQL script that can detect redundant indexes across an entire database? An example of a redundant index in a table would be as follows:

```
Index 1: 'ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC'
Index 2: 'ColumnA', 'ColumnB'
```

Ignoring other considerations, such as the width of columns and covering indexes, Index 2 would be redundant.

Thanks.

Comment: I dispute index2's redundancy. If columnC is wide, index2 may be more efficient for certain queries.  In addition, a covering index does not make redundant all non-covering indexes with the same column order.

Comment: Check this link. [www.sql-server-performance.com](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/finding_duplicate_indexes_p1.aspx) .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are situations where the redundancy doesn't hold.  For example, say `ColumnC` was a huuge field, but you'd sometimes have to retrieve it quickly.  Your `index 1` would not require a key lookup for:

```
select ColumnC from YourTable where ColumnnA = 12
```

On the other hand `index 2` is much smaller, so it can be read in memory for queries that require an index scan:

```
select * from YourTable where ColumnnA like '%hello%'
```

So they're not really redundant.

If you're not convinced by my above argument, you can find "redundant" indexes like:

```
;with ind as (
    select  a.object_id
    ,       a.index_id
    ,       cast(col_list.list as varchar(max)) as list
    from    (
            select  distinct object_id
            ,       index_id
            from    sys.index_columns
            ) a
    cross apply
            (
            select  cast(column_id as varchar(16)) + ',' as [text()]
            from    sys.index_columns b
            where   a.object_id = b.object_id
                    and a.index_id = b.index_id
            for xml path(''), type
            ) col_list (list)
)
select  object_name(a.object_id) as TableName
,       asi.name as FatherIndex
,       bsi.name as RedundantIndex
from    ind a
join    sys.sysindexes asi
on      asi.id = a.object_id
        and asi.indid = a.index_id
join    ind b
on      a.object_id = b.object_id
        and a.object_id = b.object_id
        and len(a.list) > len(b.list)
        and left(a.list, LEN(b.list)) = b.list
join    sys.sysindexes bsi
on      bsi.id = b.object_id
        and bsi.indid = b.index_id
```

Bring cake for your users in case performance decreases "unexpectedly" :-)

Comment: Thanks - But I'm not interested in whether, in your opinion, you think index 2 is redundant with index 1. I'm interested in a T-SQL script that gives me a heads up that an index might be redundant with another index.

Comment: The issue isn't whether I believe you or not. And my question was not about what constitutes a redundant index. It would be nice if more people would just answer the question, as posted, and not try to answer a question that wasn't asked. I simply wanted a query that gave me a heads up on what indexes might be redundant, and then we will evaluate each one to decide what action to take.

BTW - nice query!

Comment: Wow.. +1'd Andomar's answer for having to deal with attitude like this... I'm certainly grateful for those who know more than I do taking the time to point out an aspect of my question I may not have considered or realized. Thanks @Andomar

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [Paul Nielsen](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2008/06/25/find-duplicate-indexes.aspx), I wrote this query to find/distinguish:

- Duplicates (ignoring include order)
- Redundant (different include columns)
- Overlapping (different index columns)

And also record their usage
(One might also want to use `is_descending_key`, but I don't need it.)

```
WITH IndexColumns AS
(
    SELECT I.object_id AS TableObjectId, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(I.object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(I.object_id) AS TableName, I.index_id AS IndexId, I.name AS IndexName
        , (IndexUsage.user_seeks + IndexUsage.user_scans + IndexUsage.user_lookups) AS IndexUsage
        , IndexUsage.user_updates AS IndexUpdates

       , (SELECT CASE is_included_column WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE column_id END AS [data()]
        FROM sys.index_columns AS IndexColumns
        WHERE IndexColumns.object_id = I.object_id
          AND IndexColumns.index_id = I.index_id
        ORDER BY index_column_id, column_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS ConcIndexColumnNrs

       ,(SELECT CASE is_included_column WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE COL_NAME(I.object_id, column_id) END AS [data()]
        FROM sys.index_columns AS IndexColumns
        WHERE IndexColumns.object_id = I.object_id
          AND IndexColumns.index_id = I.index_id
        ORDER BY index_column_id, column_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS ConcIndexColumnNames

       ,(SELECT CASE is_included_column WHEN 1 THEN column_id ELSE NULL END AS [data()]
        FROM sys.index_columns AS IndexColumns
        WHERE IndexColumns.object_id = I.object_id
        AND IndexColumns.index_id = I.index_id
        ORDER BY column_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS ConcIncludeColumnNrs

       ,(SELECT CASE is_included_column WHEN 1 THEN COL_NAME(I.object_id, column_id) ELSE NULL END AS [data()]
        FROM sys.index_columns AS IndexColumns
        WHERE IndexColumns.object_id = I.object_id
          AND IndexColumns.index_id = I.index_id
        ORDER BY column_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS ConcIncludeColumnNames
    FROM sys.indexes AS I
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS IndexUsage
        ON IndexUsage.object_id = I.object_id
          AND IndexUsage.index_id = I.index_id
          AND IndexUsage.Database_id = db_id() 
)
SELECT
  C1.TableName
  , C1.IndexName AS 'Index1'
  , C2.IndexName AS 'Index2'
  , CASE WHEN (C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs = C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs) AND (C1.ConcIncludeColumnNrs = C2.ConcIncludeColumnNrs) THEN 'Exact duplicate'
        WHEN (C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs = C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs) THEN 'Different includes'
        ELSE 'Overlapping columns' END
--  , C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs
--  , C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs
  , C1.ConcIndexColumnNames
  , C2.ConcIndexColumnNames
--  , C1.ConcIncludeColumnNrs
--  , C2.ConcIncludeColumnNrs
  , C1.ConcIncludeColumnNames
  , C2.ConcIncludeColumnNames
  , C1.IndexUsage
  , C2.IndexUsage
  , C1.IndexUpdates
  , C2.IndexUpdates
  , 'DROP INDEX ' + C2.IndexName + ' ON ' + C2.TableName AS Drop2
  , 'DROP INDEX ' + C1.IndexName + ' ON ' + C1.TableName AS Drop1
FROM IndexColumns AS C1
  INNER JOIN IndexColumns AS C2 
    ON (C1.TableObjectId = C2.TableObjectId)
    AND (
         -- exact: show lower IndexId as 1
            (C1.IndexId < C2.IndexId
            AND C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs = C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs
            AND C1.ConcIncludeColumnNrs = C2.ConcIncludeColumnNrs)
         -- different includes: show longer include as 1
         OR (C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs = C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs
            AND LEN(C1.ConcIncludeColumnNrs) > LEN(C2.ConcIncludeColumnNrs))
         -- overlapping: show longer index as 1
         OR (C1.IndexId <> C2.IndexId
            AND C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs <> C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs
            AND C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs like C2.ConcIndexColumnNrs + ' %')
    )
ORDER BY C1.TableName, C1.ConcIndexColumnNrs
```

Comment: Sir, you deserve a medal! 

Answer (score 3):

Try the script below to show Unused Indexes, hope it helps

```
/****************************************************************
Description: Script to show Unused Indexes using DMVs
****************************************************************/

SELECT TOP 100
o.name AS ObjectName
, i.name AS IndexName
, i.index_id AS IndexID  
, dm_ius.user_seeks AS UserSeek
, dm_ius.user_scans AS UserScans
, dm_ius.user_lookups AS UserLookups
, dm_ius.user_updates AS UserUpdates
, p.TableRows
, 'DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) 
+ ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(dm_ius.object_id)) as 'drop statement'
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dm_ius  
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.index_id = dm_ius.index_id AND dm_ius.object_id = i.object_id   
INNER JOIN sys.objects o on dm_ius.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(p.rows) TableRows, p.index_id, p.object_id 
                FROM sys.partitions p GROUP BY p.index_id, p.object_id) p 
        ON p.index_id = dm_ius.index_id AND dm_ius.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(dm_ius.object_id,'IsUserTable') = 1
AND dm_ius.database_id = DB_ID()   
AND i.type_desc = 'nonclustered'
AND i.is_primary_key = 0
AND i.is_unique_constraint = 0
ORDER BY (dm_ius.user_seeks + dm_ius.user_scans + dm_ius.user_lookups) ASC
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the following query that gives me a lot of good information to identify duplicate and near-duplicate indexes.  It also includes other information like how many pages of memory an index takes, which allows me to give a higher priority to larger indexes.  It shows what columns are indexed and what columns are included, so I can see if there are two indexes that are almost identical with only slight variations in the included columns.

```
WITH IndexSummary AS
(

SELECT DISTINCT sys.objects.name AS [Table Name],
    sys.indexes.name AS [Index Name],
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' +  sys.columns.Name as [text()]
        FROM sys.columns
            INNER JOIN sys.index_columns
                ON sys.index_columns.column_id = sys.columns.column_id
                AND sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
        WHERE sys.index_columns.index_id = sys.indexes.index_id
            AND sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
            AND sys.index_columns.is_included_column = 0
        ORDER BY sys.columns.name
    FOR XML Path('')), 2, 10000) AS [Indexed Column Names],
    ISNULL(SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' +  sys.columns.Name as [text()]
        FROM sys.columns
            INNER JOIN sys.index_columns
            ON sys.index_columns.column_id = sys.columns.column_id
            AND sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
        WHERE sys.index_columns.index_id = sys.indexes.index_id
            AND sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
            AND sys.index_columns.is_included_column = 1
        ORDER BY sys.columns.name
        FOR XML Path('')), 2, 10000), '') AS [Included Column Names],
    sys.indexes.index_id, sys.indexes.object_id
FROM sys.indexes
    INNER JOIN SYS.index_columns
        ON sys.indexes.index_id = SYS.index_columns.index_id
            AND sys.indexes.object_id = sys.index_columns.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects
        ON sys.OBJECTS.object_id = SYS.indexES.object_id
WHERE sys.objects.type = 'U'
)

SELECT IndexSummary.[Table Name],
    IndexSummary.[Index Name],
    IndexSummary.[Indexed Column Names],
    IndexSummary.[Included Column Names],
    PhysicalStats.page_count as [Page Count],
    CONVERT(decimal(18,2), PhysicalStats.page_count * 8 / 1024.0) AS [Size (MB)],
    CONVERT(decimal(18,2), PhysicalStats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent) AS [Fragment %]
FROM IndexSummary
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
       AS PhysicalStats
        ON PhysicalStats.index_id = IndexSummary.index_id
            AND PhysicalStats.object_id = IndexSummary.object_id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) as Computed
        FROM IndexSummary Summary2
        WHERE Summary2.[Table Name] = IndexSummary.[Table Name]
            AND Summary2.[Indexed Column Names] = IndexSummary.[Indexed Column Names]) > 1
ORDER BY [Table Name], [Index Name], [Indexed Column Names], [Included Column Names]
```

Results of the query look like this:

```
Table Name  Index   Indexed Cols    Included Cols   Pages   Size (MB)   Frag %
My_Table    Indx_1     Col1         Col2, Col3       123      0.96       8.94
My_Table    Indx_2     Col1         Col2, Col3       123      0.96       8.94
```

#### Complete Description

For the complete explanation see **[Identifying Duplicate or Redundant Indexes in SQL Server](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/query-to-identify-duplicate-or-redundant-indexes-in-sql-server/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading some MSDN blogs, noticed a [script to do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/06/29/detecting-overlapping-indexes-in-sql-server-2005.aspx) and remembered this question.

I haven't bothered testing it side by side with Andomar's to see if one has any particular benefit over the other.

One amendment I would likely make to both though would be to take into account the size of both indexes when assessing redundancy.

**Edit:**

Also see Kimberley Tripp's post on [Removing duplicate indexes](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/RemovingDuplicateIndexes.aspx)