# Is this index redundant?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

A recent review of a fairly high traffic table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [time](0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tracks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

reveals the following index definitions:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i1] ON [dbo].[SomeTable] 
(
    [SomeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

-and-

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i2] ON [dbo].[SomeTable] 
(
    [SomeId] ASC,
    [OtherId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This area isn't really my strength, but isn't index `i1` superfluous?

Comment: Table definition including clustered index key and datatypes? The first one is a bit narrower so could be preferred if `OtherId` was very wide. Alternatively If `OtherId` is part of the CI key then it will also be a hidden part of the first NCI key anyway.

Comment: It looks redundant to me... `[SomeId]` is a leading column in `[i2]`, and can be used effectively for the same queries as `[i1]`.

Comment: @spender - Can't see any info about either datatypes or the CI key.

Comment: @spender - `OtherId` is only 4 bytes so basically redundant then. Queries that only look up by `SomeId` might get a slightly reduced number of reads from using it but probably not worth the overhead except if your DB is more or less read only and all fits in cache so having the two very similar copies isn't displacing anything more useful.

Comment: [Or sometimes a narrower index with the same leading key can help with deadlocks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7285041/73226). But still probably redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, maybe not. If you were the optimizer, which index would you use for the following query:

```
select [SomeId]
from [dbo].[SomeTable]
```

If that query is the kind that's critical to your application and the table is large, having that targeted index could be useful. But you're right in that any query that could be satisfied by i1 could also be satisfied (perhaps more expensively) by i2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is redundant.  You'll often end up with this kind of situation when someone adds a new index without reviewing whether it makes any existing indices redundant.

You'll find it worthwhile reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283666/t-sql-for-finding-redundant-indexes) that describes circumstances where the apparrently redundant index would be useful.  However, since your table doesn't contain large columns, it won't apply to you.

For reference, [this blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/RemovingDuplicateIndexes.aspx) describes how you can eliminate redundant indices from your databases.

Answer (score 1):

You should not only think about the width of the extra column in the `i2` when you are weighting the redundance of the index but also the granularity of it in relation of the first column.

If `OtherId` has and takes a lot of values for every valor of the `SomeId` col, queries with only `SomeId` in the where will take more time without the seemingly redundant index than with it.