# how to find duplicate indexes in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [T-SQL for finding Redundant Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283666/t-sql-for-finding-redundant-indexes)

how to find duplicate indexes in a table ,example a nonclustered index names FX_LOCATION_ID is created on columns a,b and again there is a nonclustered index named FX_LOCATION_ID1  on the same columns a,b in a table.Now i want to find the duplicate indexes on all the tables in a database,does anybody has any sql script  in handy that i can use.

Comment: [Removing duplicate indexes](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/RemovingDuplicateIndexes.aspx)

Comment: See [how to find duplicate indexes](http://thomaslarock.com/2010/08/how-to-find-duplicate-indexes/) by Thomas LaRock - he has a script to find those duplicates